# How to create variables with the contents of matrix arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array with identifiers like this "name" => "Manoel", "age" => 45 then how can I turn them into individual variables without having to know each identifier in the array? is it possible?

Can I do that inside a class to create new properties?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it would help to know why you want to do this...

Comment: Maybe he's trying to implement a simple ORM, considering his second question.

Comment: Your answer should work (I had never heard of `extract()`, cool stuff)... that said, this question makes my bad-code-design bones tingle.

Comment: I was told this is a good practice to create global variables out of a array of configuration while creating the data base access information.

Comment: @HamzaKubba, Yes? Thanks! How about voting me up? This guy won't (can't) yet... ;-)

Comment: @EASI Heh, sure, done...
@SkyHunter Hmmmm... well I guess if you want to create arbitrary global variables, that will work, but it does seem kind of 'dangerous' in that you could overwrite other variables, and in that you're not guaranteed the variables you're looking for will exist.

Consider creating an object with all the fields you need, but the fields are empty, e.g. `$defaultConfig = ["host" => "localhost", "username" => null, ... ];`, then merge that default config with the config you're reading, e.g. `$config = array_merge($defaultConfig, $myConfig);`. That way, `$config` is consistent

Comment: I do not understand what is happening to my questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <?php
    $Wales = 'Swansea \n';
    print $Wales;
    $capitalcities['England'] = 'London';
    $capitalcities['Scotland'] = 'Edinburgh';
    $capitalcities['Wales'] = 'Cardiff';
    extract($capitalcities);
    print $Wales;
 ?>
```

The result you should see in your browser is:

```
Swansea
Cardiff
```

And **yes**, if you do this inside an **object** you may have those variables as properties in execution time.

Comment: I've tested. It works. That's exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it works... just be careful not to do this kind of thing too often. :)